# How waiting async return in a sync function

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous

I'm working on a react native app, in App.js before my App function I fetch my token in the AsyncStorage and in the App function I check if this token exist or if he's not expired.
But to get informations in AsyncStorage use Async function and my App function can't be async. The App function will be call later by react native, so I can't use 'then' and callback.

```js
let token;
let expirationDate;
AsyncStorage.getItem('accessToken').then((response) => token = response)
AsyncStorage.getItem('expirationTokenDate').then((response) => expirationDate = response)

const App = () => {
    if (!token | !expirationDate | expirationDate < Date.now()) {
        //return something
    }
    //return another thing
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can't block async function in JavaScript, so you must use sync api

Comment: You can not make asynchronous operations synchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your variables into state ie:

```
const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
const [expirationTokenDate, setExpirationTokenDate] = useState(null);

AsyncStorage.getItem('accessToken').then((response) => setToken(response.data)
AsyncStorage.getItem('expirationTokenDate').then((response) => setExpirationTokenDate(response.data)

const App = () => {
    if (!token | !expirationDate | expirationDate < Date.now()) {
        //return something
    }
    //return another thing
}
```

Comment: They should probably be properties of the same state rather than separate states.